# django 404 not found page

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I am trying to show a blogpost on the site.

Below is details of `urls` and `view` file details but still it showing a `404 not found page`

#### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="ShopHome"),
    path("blogpost/", views.blogpost, name="blogpost")
]
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html')

def blogpost(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/blogpost.html')
```

Showing:

> 404 not found page

Comment: what URL are you trying to access when you get the 404?

Answer (score 0):

you should include `urls.py` of your application to project `urls.py`

actually if your project name is "`mysite`" and your application name is "`blogspot`", you should include `mysite/blogspot/urls.py` on this file `mysite/mysite/urls.py` like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include('blogspot.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i forget to add the slash at the time of registering the url of this app in urls